# Update dataframe value conditionaly with its own value

Tags: python, pandas

I have DF with float street numbers, sometime it is "NaN" or "x-y" (ex: 30-32) but often x.y (ex: 32.0 instead of 30)
I need to change this to int (if there is no "-" in the number of course).
Ive tried

```
chunk.loc["-" not in chunk["Street Number"] & chunk["Street Number"].notna(), 'Street Number'] = chunk["Street Number"].astype(int)
```

I know there is an issue after my "=" sign. How to update dataframe value conditionaly with its own value please ?
Ive also tried with

```
chunk[["Street Number"]].astype(int)
```

There is no error

> Sample of DF :
>
> 0    |    NaN
>
> 1    |    1.0
>
> 2    |    6.0
>
> 3    |  170.0
>
> 4    |   61.0
>
> 5    |   51-52

I tried to force dtype "Street Number": np.uint16 but I got ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 12

Comment: Could you share a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: So you want `51-52` to become `NaN`?

Comment: @Chris not at all, I want 30.0 to become 30

Answer (score 1):

Use changed [Cedric H. solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56750024/2901002), but in output are mixed strings, integers, floats (`NaN`)s:

```
def convert_street_number_values(x):
    try:
        x = float(x)
        if x.is_integer():
            return int(x)
        else:
            return x
    except Exception:
        return x

chunk = pd.DataFrame({'Street Number':[np.nan, '1.0', '6.0', '170.0', '61.0', '51-52']})

chunk['Street Number'] = chunk['Street Number'].apply(convert_street_number_values)
print (chunk)
  Street Number
0           NaN
1             1
2             6
3           170
4            61
5         51-52
```

EDIT:

Problem is if multiple different groups - then pandas convert column to integers, but if there is at least one `NaN`s value it convert back to `floats`.

Solution working nice for all data is converting to `strings`:

```
def convert_street_number_values(x):
    try:
        x = float(x)
        if x.is_integer():
            return str(int(x))
        else:
            return str(x)
    except Exception:
        return str(x)
```

Because converting to integers with missing values is possible using [Nullable Integer Data Type](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
chunk['Street Number'] = chunk['Street Number'].astype('Int64')
```

but it failed if at least string value.

So if convert all non numeric to `NaN`s it working:

```
chunk['Street Number'] = pd.to_numeric(chunk['Street Number'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

Comment: Not working for me... 

'''chunk['Street Number'].apply(convert_street_number_values)
print(chunk["Street Number"])'''

Comment: No error, just floats everywhere https://www.noelshack.com/2019-26-2-1561453003-capture.png

Comment: @TTeaTie - You forget assign back `chunk['Street Number'] = chunk['Street Number'].apply(convert_street_number_values)`

Comment: It changes nothing, still have float even with assigning back

Comment: @TTeaTie - What is your pandas version?

Comment: python: 3.6.8.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
machine&processor: x86_64
byteorder: little

pandas: **0.24.2**
 @jezrael thx a lot for your help. I hope we will success to resolve this.
I figured out that your example is working with your example dataframe but I cannot apply it to my dataframe...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195504/discussion-between-jezrael-and-t-tea-tie).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def convert_street_number_values(v):
    # Add more complex 'rules' as you need
    try:
        return int(v)
    except Exception:
        return v

df['Steet Number'].apply(convert_street_number_values)
```

Comment: But ValueError will be in the catch block anuway. Not sure what you tried